# How to set Cursor blink rate = 1, or 1/2 second?

Tags: windows, text-cursor

In windows, the cursor blink rate setting is not related to seconds. Is there a way to make it?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess they want you to pick it visually, but in the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\CursorBlinkRate` you can see [it's a value in milliseconds](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757455(v=WS.10).aspx).

Here are the values going from the leftmost slider notch to the right:

- Never blink
- 1.2 seconds
- 1.1 seconds
- **1 second**
- 0.9 seconds
- 0.8 seconds
- 0.7 seconds
- 0.6 seconds
- **0.5 seconds**
- 0.4 seconds
- 0.3 seconds
- 0.2 seconds

The default value is `530`, so based on what the GUI shows us you'll need to manually edit the key to get that magic number back.